# Mongoose: FindOneAndUpdate() with query from field reference

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
var WorkstationSchema = new Schema({
    tag: { type : String },
    address : { type : String , unique : true, required : true },
    status: { type : String , required : true },
});


    var ProblemSchema = new Schema({
        type: { type: Number, default: 0 },
        status: { type: Number, default: 0 },
        dateCreated: { type: String, trim: true, default: '' },
        workstation: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Workstation'},
    });

    conditions = {type: problemType, status: 0, 'workstation.address': remote64};
    update = {status: 1};

    ProblemSchema.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, options).populate('workstation', 'address').exec(function (err, problem) {
          if(err){
             //do something
          } else {
                console.log(problem);
              }

    });
```

These are my entities and I need to find a problem that has a workstation with this address and update the problem status.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply match condition without `workstation.address` to find problem and populate and after that match `workstation.address` to update status.

```
conditions = {type: problemType, status: 0};

ProblemSchema.find(conditions).populate("workstation", "address").exec(function(error, docs){ 
  docs.forEach(function (problem) {
    if(problem.workstation && problem.workstation.address === remote64) {
      problem.status = 1;
      problem.save(function(err, doc) {
        if(err){
          //do something
        } else {
          console.log(doc);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, but this solution don't work. Because forEach is not a function.
TypeError: ProblemSchema.find(...).populate(...).snapshot(...).forEach is not a function

Comment: Now, it works! Thanks, but one more question. If I have more than two problems but I want to edit only one. How can I do?

Comment: just return from `else` condition

Comment: Thanks. This is what that I thought.

Answer (score 0):

In mongoose you cannot perform multi-collections requests.

What you can do is:

- Find Problem's documents that match problemType/Status
- then check the workstation address
- then update the status
- then save the documents

*Something like (example)*:

```
// Get document that match our requirements
// And populate the workstation

ProblemSchema.find({
    type: problemType,
    status: 0,
 }).populate('workstation')
   .exec()
   .then((docs = []) => {
      // Get elements that match the address
      const matchingElems = docs.filter((x) => x.workstation.address === remote64));

      // If no element matching
      if (!matchingElems.length) return;

      // Modify all status
      matchingElems.forEach((x, xi) => (matchingElems[xi].status = 1));

      // Then save all documents
      return this.customFunctionSaveAllDocuments(matchingElems);
   })
   .then(() => ...) // Next code
   .catch(...); // Handle errors
```

(Here I use es6 syntax and Promise)